# I put "text-decoration: none" everywhere on my css, but none works

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

everything is said in the title, I tried a lot of things, but nothing works, I don't understand why, it's my first time I have this problem.

In any div, nothing work !

I've seen forums trying out "a: link {text-decoration: none! Important" and variations with "important" but nothing works and I don't know where it came from.

My code :

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
   
}

a:link, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    padding-right: 20px;
    word-spacing: 12px;
    
}

.nav .right a .item 

{
    font-size:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}



.nav .right .accountButton 
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    background-color:#76dafb;
    border:none;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-top:9px;
}

.google {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 110px;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.share
{
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    margin-top:140px;
    margin-left:15px;
}

.bar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 575px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    
}

    .bar:hover {
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #dcdcdc;
    }

    .bar:focus-within {
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 1px #dcdcdc;
        outline: none;
    }
.searchbar {
    height: 45px;
    border: none;
    width: 500px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 70px;
}
.voice {
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    bottom:2px;
    left: 30px;
}

.search {
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 510px;
    opacity:0.5
}

.buttons 
{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size:14px;

}

.button {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size:15px;
}

    .button:hover {
        border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
        padding: 9px 19px;
        color: #808080;

    }


footer {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-top: solid 2px #e4e4e4;
    margin-top: 360px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 10px #f2f2f2;
}
footer .footer a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
footer .footer .first {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}


footer .second 
{
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    opacity:0.7;    

}
 
footer .second .items

{
    padding:12px;
    font-size:15px;
    
}
footer .right
{
    margin-left:200px;
}
    footer .right .r-item {
        
        padding: 12px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    footer .middle {
        margin-left: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="right">
            <a href="http://gmail.com/" class="item">Gmail</a>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=FR" class="item">Images</a>
            <a class="item"><img src="images/box.jpg"></a>
            <a href="#account">
                <button type="button" class="accountButton">M</button>
            </a>


        </div>
        

        </div>
    
    <div class="google">
        <img src="images/gif.gif" />
        <img src="images/share.png" class="share" />
    </div>

    <div class="bar">
        <input class="searchbar" type="text" title="Search">
        <a href="#"> <img class="voice" src="images/mic.png" title="Search by Voice"></a>
        <a href="#"> <img class="search" src="images/search.svg" title="SearchLogo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button" type="button">Recherche Google</button> 
        <button class="button" type="button">J'ai de la chance</button>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="first">
                <p>France</p>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="second">
                <div class="left">
                    <a href="https://about.google/?utm_source=google-FR&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=hp-footer&fg=1" style="text-decoration:none "class="items">À propos</a>
                    <a href="https://ads.google.com/intl/fr_fr/home/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpafoot1_1!o2m--ahpm-0000000068-0000000002&utm_source=google.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=google_hpafooter&fg=1" class="items">Publicité</a>
                    <a href="https://smallbusiness.withgoogle.com/intl/fr_fr/?subid=fr-fr-et-g-awa-a-g_hpbfoot1_1!o2&utm_source=google&utm_medium=ep&utm_campaign=google_hpbfooter&utm_content=google_hpbfooter&gmbsrc=fr-fr-et-gs-z-gmb-s-z-u~sb-g4sb_srvcs-u#!/" class="items">Entreprise</a>
                    <a href="https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/?fg=1" class="items">Comment fonctionne la recherche Google ?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="middle">
                    <a href="https://sustainability.google/intl/fr/commitments-europe/?utm_source=googlehpfooter&utm_medium=housepromos&utm_campaign=bottom-footer&utm_content=">Neutre en carbone depuis 2007</a>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <a href="https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/7585859?p=fr_consumer_info&hl=fr&fg=1&visit_id=637533038681009770-2020925636&rd=1" class="r-item">Info consommateurs</a>
                    <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=fr&fg=1" class="r-item">Confidentialité</a>
                    <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=fr&fg=1" class="r-item">Conditions</a>
                    <a href="#" class="r-item">Paramètres</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the rule for `a:visited`. Or just pass `a {text-decoration: none ! important} `

Comment: Why are you recreating the Google home page? :P

Comment: hahaha i'm in formation and the excercice is recreate the google home page ^^

Comment: Great Reason! .. This Page can help you : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: Thanks Kevin for this link ! it helped me a lot and I managed to solve my problem !